# My Site URL only Works when clicked from the Inside

Tags: php, smf

I've not been too frustrated like this trying to fix something.

I'm almost done moving to SMF, what's left is the readable URL.

I customized pretty URL to match the URL.
http://test.example.com/1234/how-to-run

if I click the url within or on the site, it opens and maybe if I copy that url I just opened into another tab it works.

But going directly to the url by just typing it in the address bar redirects to homepage.

If I then visit the url on my site and try again, it works.

I need help please

Comment: why are you **SHOUTING/YELLING** at us?

Comment: where is your code? and SEO as tagged, is off-topic here.

Comment: The behavior you describe would indicate that your site is likely not allowing people to directly access the pages unless the referrer is set (either to that site or non-empty). This might be something in (for example) .htaccess if you're on Apache, or some sort of configuration you have set in SMF.

Comment: I'm not shouting @Funk

Comment: It's actually a subdomain

Comment: your original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52268102/1 contained CAPS. Those are considered as yelling characters.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was from the subdomain. I don't know if it has anything to do with the host. After moving the site to main domain (example.com), it worked fine.